# SVG embedded font gets overwritten in Internet Edge

Tags: svg, fonts, microsoft-edge

I'm using vecta.io to create SVG images for my website, some of which include embedded fonts. I embed these simply via an `<img src="this.svg">` tag.

This works as needed on Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer - but not Microsoft Edge.

Specifically on Edge, the embedded font gets replaced by Times New Roman when using the `<img>` tag - but not when using the `<object>` tag for inserting the SVG. I wish to use the image tag for simplicity and ideally avoid fallbacks - is there a way to solve this on Edge?

Below is an example of the problem - an SVG with embedded fonts inserted both via image tag and object tag: https://test123new.smoolis.com/screen/page/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue of Edge Legacy. I found [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122843/serialized-svg-image-with-base64-embedded-font-not-rendering-correctly-in-ie-ed) and others have reported the issue. You could also provide your feedback in Edge Legacy.

As a workaround for now, if you don't want to use `<object>` tag, I think you can only save the picture as a png file and use png pic in Edge Legacy.